# Does the recommended approach of Nested Extensions for Google Protocol Buffers work for deep, single inheritance hierarchies?

Tags: c++, inheritance, serialization, protocol-buffers

I have read that the recommended way to deal with inheritance in Google Protocol Buffers (protobuf) is to utilize Nested Extensions. From [idelible.org](http://www.indelible.org/ink/protobuf-polymorphism/):

> The final (and most generally recommended) approach uses a combination of [nested messages](http://code.google.com/apis/protocolbuffers/docs/proto.html#nested) and extensions to implemented polymorphic message types. This works by having each subclass reference itself from within a nested extension of the base type. An explicit type field is still required to guide the deserialization process. [...] This approach tends to be the most efficient and robust implementation, albeit a bit non-obvious to protocol buffer newcomers.

```
message Animal
{
    extensions 100 to max;

    enum Type
    {
        Cat = 1;
        Dog = 2;
    }

    required Type type = 1;
}

message Cat
{
    extend Animal
    {
        required Cat animal = 100; // Unique Animal extension number
    }

    // These fields can use the full number range.
    optional bool declawed = 1;
}

message Dog
{
    extend Animal
    {
        required Dog animal = 101; // Unique Animal extension number
    }

    // These fields can use the full number range.
    optional uint32 bones_buried = 1;
}
```

I have a much more complex inheritance hierarchy (C++), only using single inheritance, but several levels deep. So my questions, before I begin implementing using this technique for my object hierarchy, are:

1. *Does this approach work reliably and efficiently for deeply nested hierarchies as well?*
2. *Is it still the recommended approach? Are there alternatives beyond redundantly implementing each object as a (free-standing) message?*

Comment: what did you end up doing?

Comment: I used nested messages in the end, to ease maintenance. I.e. message Base { ... } message Derived { Base base = 1;  ... }

Comment: Yeah, that's what we did as well - not ideal, but best of available options I think. Thanks

Comment: The indelible.org link is spot on. Sounds like 8 years on his desire goes unfulfilled... _Perhaps something along these lines will be undertaken by a motivated developer or an ambitious Google Summer of Code student._